# Link error when trying to call a fortran subroutine using C++ code

Tags: c++, macos, fortran, clang, linker-errors

I am currently trying to use some fortran subroutines in my C++ program. However, I have never tried it before, so I write a simple code sample to try hybrid programming.

I have "gcc version 12.1.0 (GCC) " and "Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)". And my operating system is macOS Monterey 12.6.

The Fortran code(test_f.f90) is as follows:

```
subroutine PRINT_NUMBER()
    use iso_c_binding 
    implicit none

    write(*,*) "This is fortran answering!"
    
end subroutine PRINT_NUMBER
```

It just does a simple print process.

The C++ code(test_c.cpp) is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
    void print_number_();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is C++ answering!" << std::endl;
    print_number_();

    return 0;
}
```

It calls the subroutine in the fortran code file to print "This is fortran answering!" and print "This is C++ answering!" itself.

I used gfortran(gcc version 12.1.0) to compile the fortran code and g++(Apple clang version 14.0.0) to compile the C++ code:

```
gfotran -c test_f.f90
g++ -c test_c.cpp
```

I got the two object files test_f.o and test_c.o

Then I tried to link these two object files:

```
g++ -o a.out test_f.o test_c.o
```

I got the error message as follows:

```
ld: warning: object file (test_f.o) was built for newer macOS version (12.5) than being linked (12.0)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__gfortran_st_write", referenced from:
      _print_number_ in test_f.o
  "__gfortran_st_write_done", referenced from:
      _print_number_ in test_f.o
  "__gfortran_transfer_character_write", referenced from:
      _print_number_ in test_f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I noticed that the gfortran library didn't work here, so I locate the gfortran library using:

```
locate libgfortran
```

and I got

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10/libgfortran.5.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10/libgfortran.a
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10/libgfortran.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10/libgfortran.spec
/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib
/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.a
/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.dylib
/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.la
/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.spec
```

I tried again to use the static library libgfortran.a to link the objects:

```
g++ -o a.out /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.a test_c.o test_f.o
```

except some "warning: object file (/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.a(...)) was built for newer macOS version (12.3) than being linked (12.0)" warnings I got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___divtf3", referenced from:
      _determine_en_precision in libgfortran.a(write.o)
      _get_float_string in libgfortran.a(write.o)
  "___eqtf2", referenced from:
      _get_float_string in libgfortran.a(write.o)
  "___gttf2", referenced from:
      _determine_en_precision in libgfortran.a(write.o)
      _get_float_string in libgfortran.a(write.o)
  "___letf2", referenced from:
      _get_float_string in libgfortran.a(write.o)
  "___lttf2", referenced from:
      _determine_en_precision in libgfortran.a(write.o)
      _get_float_string in libgfortran.a(write.o)
  "___multf3", referenced from:
      _determine_en_precision in libgfortran.a(write.o)
      _get_float_string in libgfortran.a(write.o)
  "___subtf3", referenced from:
      _determine_en_precision in libgfortran.a(write.o)
      _get_float_string in libgfortran.a(write.o)
  "___unordtf2", referenced from:
      _determine_en_precision in libgfortran.a(write.o)
      _get_float_string in libgfortran.a(write.o)
  "_quadmath_snprintf", referenced from:
      _determine_en_precision in libgfortran.a(write.o)
      _get_float_string in libgfortran.a(write.o)
  "_strtoflt128", referenced from:
      __gfortrani_convert_real in libgfortran.a(read.o)
      __gfortrani_convert_infnan in libgfortran.a(read.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It still didn't work. It seems I need a lot more libraries here. I'm confused.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Note that the `use iso_c_binding` does nothing in your case. You may want to use `bind(C)` and remove the underscore in the C symbol name.

Comment: First, try to link your program using `gfortran` instead of `g++`. Then try using `-lgfortran` in the link command when using `g++`.  I highly discourage refernecing the `.a` library manually. Try also linking the libquadmath (`-lquadmath`) library.

Comment: Note that we have many previous questiins about this and there are duplicates available and your questiin is likely to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: OK, a google search revealed that those symbols come from libgcc, so try also adding `-lgcc`. Please remember that the order *does matter*. At least when using the static libraries. I still think that the main problem is from linking the `.a` library manually.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried your solution and I tried to link the two object files using: `gfortran -o a.out test_f.o test_c.o -lgfortran -lquadmath -lgcc` and I got the following error message: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: I edit my question to put the full error message.

Comment: No, that is wrong. Use `g++` with `-lgfortran` and so on. If you use `gfortran` you must use `-lstdc++` instead.

Comment: Start with `g++ -o a.out test_f.o test_c.o -lgfortran`. Add `-lgcc` or even `-lquadmath` only when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried `g++ -o a.out test_f.o test_c.o -lgfortran
` and I got `ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`. I'll find that out.

Comment: So you are using clang disguised as g++? Please show the versions of tour compilers and your operating system.

Comment: I have "gcc version 12.1.0 (GCC) " and "Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)". And my operating system is macOS Monterey 12.6.

Comment: What does `g++ -v` print?

Comment: It prints "Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin"

Comment: I tried `locate libgfortran.so` and I found that there's no such file. Maybe that's the reason for the question?

Comment: There is no `libgfortran.so` on MacOS. You have the `libgfortran.dylib` instead. Since it is in a nonstandard location, you may need to use `-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/` before `-lgfortran`.

Comment: Can you try ```gcc test_f.f90 test_c.cpp -lstdc++ -lgfortran```. Then at least you know that you will be using the same compiler family.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Thanks for your comments! I tried that and it worked. However, when running a.out, I encountered another problem. I used `./a.out` to run and I received the following message: `dyld[68474]: Library not loaded: '@rpath/libgfortran.5.dylib'
  Referenced from: '....../a.out'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file)`. I tried `install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/ /usr/local/gfortran/lib  ....../a.out` but didn't work. Any advice?

Comment: @lastchance I tried `gcc -o test_f.f90 test_c.cpp -lstdc++ -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/ -lgfortran` the same way as Vladimir said. I get: `ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/gfortran/lib//libgfortran.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (12.3) than being linked (12.0)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_print_number", referenced from:
      _main in test_c-778306.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`. There may be some linking problems.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I cheated, and it finally worked. I copied all the files in the `/usr/local/gfortran/lib` to `/usr/local/lib`. I am wondering If there's a more elegant way?

Comment: @Christ Liu, the intention of my suggestion was that you DIDN'T put a separate path to libraries in, but simply let the particular version of gcc use the libraries that IT expected to find. I suspect that a major part of the problem is that you have two different compilers (or different versions of the compiler) getting muddled up with each other.

Comment: @lastchance Thanks for your comment! It worked and I don't need to do other messy works to make it run. Using the same family of compiler is the key. Thank you!